# NULL check for nested pointers in a single if-statement

Tags: c, if-statement

```
Struct {
    int a;
    struct sample *b;
} test;

int func(struct test *t1) {
  if (!t1 || !t1->b) {  // Is this statement ok?
    return _EINVAL
  }

  ...
}
```

Is it ok to NULL check for nested pointers in a single if-statement? Can I always assume that the left check(!t1 in my example) will be performed first?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the language rules of C guarantee that if the expression `a` in `a || b` is true, then `b` is never evaluated. (A similar rule exists for `a && b` if `a` evaluates to false.) This is called [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).